# ReleaseDesignerOutlets deallocated outlets not being reallocated

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have the following scenario:

1. UIViewControllerA pushes UIViewControllerB on to the navigation stack via a storyboard segue;
2. UIViewControllerB is now currently onscreen and I simulate a memory warning via the iOS Simulator.
3. UIViewControllerA.DidReceiveMemoryWarning() gets invoked as well as UIViewControllerA.ViewDidUnload().
4. In method UIViewControllerA.ViewDidUnload() I call ReleaseDesignerOutlets() as recommended. UIViewControllerA designer outlets are now deallocated and null.
5. I hit the "back" button on the navigation bar which dismisses UIViewControllerB and causes UIViewControllerA.ViewDidLoad() to be invoked.
6. At this point I would expect the designer outlets to be initialised **but they are still null** and my application crashes due to null pointer exception.

Have I fundamentally missed something? I am using the Monotouch 5.4.0.

EDIT
I found this [post](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Getting-a-SIGABRT-on-the-device-td4410210.html#a4411696) which describes the solution to problem to be the same as what I discovered, that is, **don't** release the designer outlets in ViewDidUnload().

> Update: It's finally crash free! (or at least it seems to be)
>
> For future reference, it looks like the big lock-up was due to my **disposing of my UIWebView outlet in the ViewDidUnload event**. The UIWebView is defined in the xib, and not added as a subview in code.
>
> When memory was running low, the view unloaded and removed the UIWebView outlet. Subsequently, the ViewDidLoad event would fire again, as the app recovered (!?), but it would lock-up. **I expected the UIWebView to be reinstated in when the view reloaded** (i.e. the xib reloaded).
>
> Is this not the case? **I thought it was good practise to dispose of outlets in the ViewDidUnload event**?
>
> **As soon as I commented out** the "webView.Dispose(); webView = null;" line of code, it's been working as expected.
>
> What a day!

EDIT
Further debugging reveals that SOME designer outlets are getting reallocated such as UIImageView and UIScrollView, others such as UITextField and UIBarButtonItem are not.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Particulary how controller A is created/setup and it's `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewDidUnload`?

Comment: There is nothing really special about controller A's ViewDidLoad, it just adds an event handler to a designer outlet button. If I comment out ReleaseDesignerOutlets() from ViewDidUnload() the problem goes away, but that seems like the wrong solution ...

Comment: How are you creating controller A?  Just doing `new ControllerA()` or via a storyboard/nib, you are not calling `LoadView()` anywhere, right?

Comment: All controllers are declared in the storyboard so we have a UINavigationController -> view controller A -> view controller B. No explicit constructor calls and no LoadView().